# When I am trying to sign in using Google, I am getting error code h5.b: 12500:

Tags: android, api, firebase-authentication, google-signin, android-app-bundle

I am developing the Android app. It contains the Google sign-in. The problem is mitigating the error "h5.b: 12500:" in the release AAB.
but I checked the same thing in the release apk. It is working properly.
I got the solution from stackoverflow, but it didn't work.
I tried several solutions.

- Adding a support email address to your project in Firebase
- Check if SHA-1 fingerprints are added to the firebase project settings
- Try updating the OAuth
- Download the latest google-service.json
  I tried these things to fix the error. 
  Did anyone know? Please help me.
  Thank you.